# I want to know how lua_call works

Tags: c++, lua, binding

I'm trying to use lua in C++.
Here's my code.

```
int main() {
    lua_State* L = lua_open();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    luaL_loadfile(L, "test.lua");
    lua_call(L, 0, 0);//First lua_call, just it Runs .lua script

    lua_getglobal(L, "funcFromLua");

    int a = 10;
    lua_pushinteger(L, a);
    lua_call(L, 1, 0);//Second lua, calls funcFromLua. right?

    lua_close(L);
}
```

Does the first lua_call and the second lua_call do different things?

I'm not sure that my comments in code are correct.

only one more question, Should I do `lua_getglobal(L, "a func")` only once?

below is test.lua

```
function funcFromLua(a) 
    print("a is", a)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comments in the code are correct.

The first `lua_call` executes the contents of the loaded script, `test.lua`. This defines a global variable `funcFromLua`.

The second `lua_call` calls `funcFromLua` with `a` set to 10.